# Updating multiple rows with different primary key in one query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.1, sql-optimization

I have to update many columns in many rows in PostgreSQL 9.1. I'm currently doing it with many different `UPDATE` queries, each one that works on a different row (based on the primary key):

```
UPDATE mytable SET column_a = 12, column_b = 6 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE mytable SET column_a = 1, column_b = 45 WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE mytable SET column_a = 56, column_b = 3 WHERE id = 3;
```

I have to do several thousands of these queries.

Is there anyway I can "bulk update" lots of rows in one query in PostgreSQL? If you're using `INSERT`, you can insert multiple rows at once: (`INSERT INTO mytable (column_a, column_b) VALUES ( (12, 6), (1, 45) );`), Is there something like that for `UPDATE`?

Something like:

```
UPDATE mytable SET (id, column_a, column_b) FROM VALUES ( (1, 12, 6), (2, 1, 45), (3, 56, 3), … )
```

??

The important points is that each 'VALUE' will only update one row (based on the `WHERE id =`). Each row will have the same, fixed number of columns that need updating, but each row will have different values for each column, so `UPDATE mytable SET column_a = 12, column_b = 6 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);` won't work.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, you can (and usually it's preferred in SQL) to update several rows at once. There're a few ways to do this, but most readable and elegant I think is to use derived table with id's and values:

```
update mytable as m set
    column_a = c.column_a,
    column_b = c.column_b
from (values
    (1, 12, 6),
    (2, 1, 45),
    (3, 56, 3)
) as c(id, column_a, column_b)
where c.id = m.id
```

Not so readable, but more obvious solution would be to use `case`:

```
update mytable set
    column_a = case id when 1 then 12 when 2 then 1 when 3 then 56 end,
    column_b = case id when 1 then 6 when 2 then 45 when 3 then 3 end
where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This approach worked out great for me!!  Thanks!!  Also works with joining on multiple key/columns.  That is, "where c.id = m.id AND c.column_a=m.column_a";

Comment: I get a 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint'. I have a compound unique index and I'm trying to update multiple rows at once to resort them.

Answer (score 11):

If this applicable to your case you can use it.

```
create table test(id int, a int, b int);

insert into test(id, a, b)
values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 1),
(4, 1, 1),
(5, 1, 1),
(6, 1, 1),
(7, 1, 1);


update test as d
set a = s.a, b = s.b
from 
(
  values
  (1, 2, 2),
  (2, 2, 2)
) as s(id, a, b)
where d.id = s.id
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4617f/2)**