# Update json in postgres using multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, query-optimization

I want to update a column of JSONB objects. So If I have this table

[image: another table]
I want to delete value1 and value2 from the rows that have a as 1 then I thought this query would work

```
UPDATE
    test AS d 
SET
    b = b - s.b_value 
FROM
    (VALUES
        (1, 'value1'),
        (1, 'value2')
    )
    AS s(a, b_value) 
WHERE
    d.a = s.a
```

but it gives me this result where value1 was not eliminated.
[image: some table]

Is there a simple way to fix it? I want to make a query to delete this sort of stuff but it would be a blessing if it can be done in only one query. I got the original idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936896/updating-multiple-rows-with-different-primary-key-in-one-query-in-postgresql) and [here you can test the SQL query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/26ef0/1)

Comment: You are trying to update the same row twice in a single `update`.  That leads to inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract a `text[]` array of keys from a jsonb value like so:

```
with s (a, b_value) as (
  values (1, 'value1'), (1, 'value2')
), dels as (
  select a, array_agg(b_value) as b_values
    from s
   group by a
)
update test
   set b = b - dels.b_values
  from dels
 where dels.a = test.a;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=02d24dde577bff328e2e7a6c60ae4a38)*