# How to do a bulk update using GORM where my each row needs to be updated with different values

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Let's assume, I have the following schema,

```
type Users struct {
    ID int gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;"
    Name string gorm:"column:"name;"
    IsActive bool gorm:"column:is_active;"
    Remarks string gorm:"column:"remarks;"
}
```

I have the ids (primary key), is_active and remarks with me. Now I wanted to update these values for different ids in bulk.

I was able to see a thread related to this in, but it is not associated with gorm.
[Updating multiple rows with different primary key in one query in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936896/updating-multiple-rows-with-different-primary-key-in-one-query-in-postgresql)

What I'm trying to achieve is to do the following:

Instead of updating one by one,

```
UPDATE users SET is_active = true, remarks = 'activated_by_cron' where id = 1;
UPDATE users SET is_active = false, remarks = 'deactivated_by_cron' where id = 2;
UPDATE users SET is_active = true, remarks = 'activated_by_user' where id = 3;
```

`

Update everything in a single query,

```
update users as u set
    is_active = c.is_active,
    remarks = c.remarks
from (values
    (1, true, 'activated_by_cron'),
    (2, false, 'deactivated_by_cron'),
    (3, true, 'activated_by_user')
) as c(id, is_active, remarks)
where c.id = u.id
```

My temporary solution was to write a custom utility function to create a raw query as explained above and then pass it to gorm to execute. But I feel this can be implemented in a better way.

Have someone faced this challenge before? If yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Maybe you can use `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE SET ...`. https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Upsert-x2F-On-Conflict

Comment: Why not just do it in a transaction and use the GORM update semantics?  db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) ( loop })?

Comment: My other related DB operations happen in bulk. So If I use a loop, this will be a bottleneck, and it will affect the total execution time.  @pilotpin